# How can I repair peeled through-hole solder pads and trace?

Tags: pcb, soldering, repair, trace

The top and bottom through-pads were torn off in a botched desoldering. The bottom pad’s trace was peeled to the solder joint.

[image: pic]

Comment: You can buy kits of replacement traces and uv cure soldermask, which you can then use to put the traces back onto the board if you want a high quality repair.  If you just want to bodge something back together, jumper around the break using wire.

Comment: If this is a mechanical part like a jack, plug, or switch, you might have to get a donor unit and use that board.  1/3 mechanical strength is asking for trouble.  Could epoxy the part on, but then what if it ever needs changed again?

Comment: Are there corresponding pads on the other side of the PCB? Do the legs of the missing component have holes in them?

Comment: In this case, I would jump wires from the solder pads below and glue the wires in place.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a fiberglass brush pen (also called a burnishing pen) and scrape away the solder mask on the trace and solder a wire from the pin to that. Sandpaper or a knife works too but you have to be a lot more careful and it's easier to mess up.

If the tear is as clean as in your photo, you can use the same methods to reveal the solder mask adjacent to the torn pad and solder bridge the pin to the exposed trace.

Both these will require on the other pins with proper pads to hold the component to the board mechanically.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd scratch off some of the solder mask from the trace that's still intact with a scalpel or similar, then solder onto the exposed copper.

In this specific case you can probably just glue the connector to the board, then connect two thin wires (some <AWG30 multi-strand with insulation) directly from the connector pins to those vias where the traces are coming from. Make sure that the wires are tight against the board and secure them with hot glue etc if necessary.